# Terraform how to apply values depending on time

Tags: terraform

I have a map that I am passing into the module, eg.

```
some_map = {
    version                  = "v2"
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
  }
```

I wanna have groups of this variables, so just the list of maps and I wanna to apply them depending on time, so eg.

```
groups = [{
    version                  = "v2"
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
    timeslot = "monday - friday" //not strict format, just for example, it can be a date in the right format
  },
{
    version                  = "v2"
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
    timeslot = "saturday - sunday" //not strict format, just for example 
  },
]
```

I can't find anything in the terraform docs related to this, so it can be probably impossible, in that case how can I emulate this logic?

Comment: And how would you use that in a module?

Comment: Just passing as a variable, don't think it's a crucial point here, just need to know is it possible to apply depending on current time

Comment: Ok, so if you're talking about applying a certain part of the variable value, that is not possible. You could do certain filtering in the module, but since I don't know what is inside it, I cannot answer it.

Comment: @MarkoE we can use intermediary variables to do the filtering... see my answer below

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true, I forgot about locals. Nice one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use an intermediary variable to filter the right version...

- changed the groups variable `timeslot` to be an array
- using a for loop with an if `contains` to filter the one we want
- we can get the day of the week with `formatdate("EEEE", timestamp())`

```
variable "groups" {
  default = [
    {
      version  = "v1"
      var1     = 1
      timeslot = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
    },
    {
      version  = "v2"
      var1     = 2
      timeslot = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]
    },
  ]
}

locals {
  data = distinct(flatten([
    for key, value in var.groups : [
      value
    ] if contains(value.timeslot, formatdate("EEEE", timestamp()))
  ]))

}

output "day_of_week" {
  value = formatdate("EEEE", timestamp())
}
output "data" {
  value = local.data[0]
}
```

...and that is all, the `local.data[0]` has what you need.

A terraform apply on that code will output:

```txt
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

data = {
  "timeslot" = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
  ]
  "var1" = 1
  "var2" = 1
  "version" = "v1"
}
day_of_week = "Thursday"
```

I tested that code with:

> Terraform v1.1.2
> on linux_amd64

Comment: actually I have a little problem, maybe you can suggest workarounds, when trying to pass data[0] to the module I am getting the error The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on. Because the for each using inside module, are there any workarounds or I need to transport this logic inside module? As I understand the dynamic creation of local causes the error.

Comment: @DISCO without code it is hard to figure out what is going on, with your existing code there is no reason for the issue you are describing, the message you shared `terraform cannot predict how many instances`  your code has no instances, I have no idea where that is from, Better to ask a new question with the new error

Comment: @DISCO just to test I changed my sample code to pass data[0] to a module like you mentioned to see if I get the same, I do not get that... the code works fine... here is my code: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/time_sensitive

Comment: I found the problem, it seems like it is not possible to use `timestamp()` within `for_each` attribute, referring to this issue https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/getting-the-the-for-each-value-depends-on-resource-attributes-that-cannot-be-determined-until-apply-so-terraform-error/12121/4 and this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21318#issuecomment-492688250. Because I am passing the variable that using `timestamp()` evaluation into the `for_each`. I did not find a solution for that case, so if you can suggest something, I will be grateful.

Comment: @DISCO I did not encountered that in any of my tests, please provide full code to reproduce what you are saying. and a new question will be better instead of keep piling up to this one

Comment: Created the new question with the sample code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220402/terraform-cant-plan-with-for-each-which-using-timestamp