# Terraform can't plan with for_each which using timestamp()

Tags: terraform

I am trying to use `timestamp()` function in `for_each` variable

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  for_each = local.alert_policies_ext_vars
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${local.alert_policies_ext_vars[0]}"
  }
}
```

which are

```
alert_policies_groups = [
    {
      version  = "v2"
      timeslot = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
    },
    {
      version  = "v2"
      timeslot = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]
    },
  ]
alert_policies_ext_vars = distinct(flatten([
    for key, value in local.alert_policies_groups : [
      merge(value, { timeslot=null })
    ] if contains(value.timeslot, formatdate("EEEE", timestamp()))
  ]))
```

Terraform plan output

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on monitoring_alert_policies.tf line 46, in resource "null_resource" "test":
  46:   for_each = local.alert_policies_ext_vars

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
```

How can I workaround that?

Comment: FWIW: The limitation is well known and written in the documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#limitations-on-values-used-in-for_each

Comment: Yep, so I am asking for the workaround

Comment: @DISCO There is no workaround. You have to use `-target` or re-design your code to never depend on uknown number of items.

Comment: does not seem that `-target` will work with `timestamp()`, re-design it is just don't use `timestamp()` in my case or don't use `for_each`, but I actually need the `timestamp()` behavior as well as `for_each`

Comment: The `alert_policies_ext_vars` contains only one value... Why are you using a `for_each` in that case?

Comment: This is just the example. In full workflow, there is n number of alert policies are created, so there is n numbers of `ext_vars` used

Comment: Please provide a proper example

Comment: What are these alert policies you mentioned? can you include those resources in your example, I get a feeling you are over complicating your code

Comment: I can't include the full code, NDA. I can try to emmulate it, but it is a lot of unneeded code for this question, I think.

Comment: Not the full code, that will be too much, just a minimal but reproducible example... start with one or two of these alert policy resources ... I really can not see why any alerts will need to change depending on the day it is deployed

Answer (score 1):

[The `timestamp` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/timestamp) returns the time of evaluation during the apply phase, and so it is unknown during the planning phase.

If the time of the *plan* phase would be an acceptable substitute, you could use [the `plantimestamp` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/plantimestamp) instead, which is guaranteed to be known during the planning phase.

---

Since Terraform is a desired state system that is designed to converge remote objects with the desired state described in the configuration, it's very unusual to use timestamps as part of the desired state because it means that the Terraform configuration can essentially never converge: time will always "change outside of Terraform", acting as a special sort of "drift".

[The `hashicorp/time` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs) offers some different ways to model time in Terraform, using managed resources instead of functions so that the provider can retain state between runs and only change the desired state when specific events occur. In your case the use of `plantimestamp` in conjunction with `formatdate` to capture only the "day of week" field is probably fine, since that will therefore only change once per day, but I've mentioned this here just in case someone else finds this answer in future and has a slightly different situation where the provider would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: It seems like there is the same error using `time_provider`. I can't use `plantimestamp` because of terrraform version, it is supported from `v1.5`.
Sample code with `time_provider`

`resource "time_static" "current_time" {}
locals{
alert_policies_ext_vars_groups = distinct(flatten([
    for key, value in var.alert_policies_ext_vars_groups : [
      merge(value, { timeslot=null })
    ] if contains(value.timeslot, time_static.current_time.day)
  ]))
}
alert_group = local.alert_policies_ext_vars_groups[0]
alert_policies = [//array of alert_policies with alert_group var]
`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for the above issue:

Instead of getting day information via terraform `timestamp` function. We can pass day information as `variables` like below.

main.tf

```
variable "day" {
  type=string
}

output "Day" {
  value=var.day
}
```

Running `terraform plan` with variables

```js
terraform plan --var=day=`date +'%A'`

Changes to Outputs:
  + Day = "Tuesday"

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure.
```

Comment: Ok, Let we rephrase that sentence.